# Using `ls' Switches Instead of Omit Mode

Tags: dired, dired-omit-mode

As per [this page](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredOmitMode)

> An alternative to using Omit mode: Use `C-u s` to change the `ls`
> switches and immediately refresh. (`C-u s` refreshes also, so there is
> very little typing involved.) You can remove `-a` from the switches to
> hide dot files, or add `-B` to hide files ending with `~`.

I entered `C-u s` and then I entered `-al -B` but this did not eliminate the files ending with `~`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see that.  For me switches `-al -B` (or `-alB`) remove `~`-suffixed file names.

Do you see it if you start Emacs with `emacs -Q` (no init file)?

- If not then bisect your init file to find the culprit.
- If yes, then what you see might depend on your `ls`.  (I'm on MS Windows, so my Emacs uses `ls-lisp.el`.)